# Why does Google Colab give a "unknown device" error when I try to convert Keras MLP?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to train a simple MLP model on google colab using a TPU.
However, when I try to convert the model with

```py
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from keras.constraints import NonNeg
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(57,input_shape=(57,)))
model.add(Dense(60,kernel_constraint=NonNeg(),activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(100,kernel_constraint=NonNeg(),activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(50,kernel_constraint=NonNeg(),activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(3,activation="linear"))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mse')

TPU_WORKER = 'grpc://' + os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR']
tpu_model = tf.contrib.tpu.keras_to_tpu_model(
    model,
    strategy=tf.contrib.tpu.TPUDistributionStrategy(
        tf.contrib.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(TPU_WORKER)))
```

gives the error `InvalidArgumentError: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU_SYSTEM:0 unknown device.` [full error here](https://pastebin.com/YVUeWTrU).

This doesn't make sense to me, because I copied the model conversion code straight from the google tutorial. When I run the test code:

```py
import os
import pprint
import tensorflow as tf

if 'COLAB_TPU_ADDR' not in os.environ:
  print('ERROR: Not connected to a TPU runtime; please see the first cell in this notebook for instructions!')
else:
  tpu_address = 'grpc://' + os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR']
  print ('TPU address is', tpu_address)

  with tf.Session(tpu_address) as session:
    devices = session.list_devices()

  print('TPU devices:')
  pprint.pprint(devices)
```

I get the expected result:

```
TPU address is grpc://10.0.203.10:8470
TPU devices:
[_DeviceAttributes(/job:tpu_worker/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0, CPU, -1, 1941375595625340814),
 _DeviceAttributes(/job:tpu_worker/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_CPU:0, XLA_CPU, 17179869184, 9079881000847066378),
 _DeviceAttributes(/job:tpu_worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:0, TPU, 17179869184, 6922694346479333534),
 _DeviceAttributes(/job:tpu_worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:1, TPU, 17179869184, 14324637633413341896),
 _DeviceAttributes(/job:tpu_worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:2, TPU, 17179869184, 3528106575831937158),
 _DeviceAttributes(/job:tpu_worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:3, TPU, 17179869184, 13852141601322651612),
 _DeviceAttributes(/job:tpu_worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:4, TPU, 17179869184, 10344791506504172772),
 _DeviceAttributes(/job:tpu_worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:5, TPU, 17179869184, 16666353711371098164),
 _DeviceAttributes(/job:tpu_worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:6, TPU, 17179869184, 3428083526573573796),
 _DeviceAttributes(/job:tpu_worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:7, TPU, 17179869184, 8632908473312514763),
 _DeviceAttributes(/job:tpu_worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU_SYSTEM:0, TPU_SYSTEM, 17179869184, 9715206562754100387)]
```

Since that works, I don't understand why the model conversion does not.

Comment: which version of tensorflow are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to make eager execution off if it is enabled.
For me it seems to go well without `tf.enable_eager_execution()` in the beginning of code.

Comment: this worked for me using tensorflow 1.13.1. i had enabled eager execution prior, so i restarted the kernel, made sure eager execution was disabled, and things worked!